# How to virus check a file(similar to what edge does after downloading)?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, antivirus

I wish to implement simple functionality of virus check to any downloaded file, similar to what Microsoft edge does. Is it possible to do so without having a own antivirus engine?

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. How would you expect to be able to identify it as a virus without an AV engine?

Comment: Okay, well then how does Microsoft edge does it, uses defender engine I guess. Well is there any way we developers can use it as well. Are there any APIs available?

Comment: Actually the question is quite clear to me. The OP is asking for a similar process that Edge uses when a file finishes downloading. In that moment a AV check is performed and as Edge is a UWP app, this is what the OP wanted to do as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no public API that would allow you to check a downloaded file for viruses. The process Edge uses is not available to developers and it does not seem Defender registers a documented URI scheme that could launch a check of a file.

Comment: Would wish Microsoft to add it sometimes later this year!

Comment: You can certainly add your suggestion in Windows 10 Feedback Hub and in the Winows Platform User Voice page - https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform. I think it is actually a very nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports the [Anti-Malware Scanning Interface (AMSI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889868(v=vs.85).aspx) that applications can use to request that a buffer be scanned by the local A/V system.

The API is not usable from a UWP application, but is usable from a Desktop application.